# Placement and use of Function and Methods

Tags: c++, function, methods

I have some code that manipulates a database, for this it requires a class to translate the rows of a table into.

Below is part of the `.h` file I have right now of the class in question, with its prototypes, which are then defined in a `.cpp` file:

```
namespace A {
namespace B {
namespace C {

class recEvent
{
public:
  struct filedEvent
  {
    int id;
    std::string title;
    std::string desc;
    std::string stime;
    std::string dur;
    int recid;
    int venid;
  };

  recEvent();
  recEvent(int recid, std::string title, std::string description, int duration,
           recurringType recurType, time_t startFrom, endType endingType,
           time_t dateEnd, int occurences, int venueid);

  void setId(int recid);
  void setTitle(std::string title);
  // ...

  int getId();
  std::string getTitle();
  // ...
};

} // A
} // B
} // C
```

I then have the prototype functions that deal with the database within this header, the problem I have is that these functions do not deal with any of the values in `RecEvent`, however they use `recEvent` classes to work [like creating vectors of type `recEvent`].

Just to ask the question, where would be best to declare / define these functions, they don't particularly require to be within a class, and are just a bunch of functions that work together to do a couple of database queries like so:

The public `fetchRecEv()` method prototype in class header `recEv`:

```
std::vector<recEvent> fectchRecEv();
```

the `.cpp` definition:

```
std::vector<recEvent> recEvent::fetchRecEv()
{
    Pocco::Data::Session* db_session = this->platform->getLocalInterfaceSession();
    Statement ss(*db_session);
    std::vector<recEvent> allRecEv;

    ss < "SELECT Id,Title,Description,Duration,RecurringType,StartFrom,EndType,DateEnd,Occurences,Venueid FROM RecurringEvents", now;
    Poco::Data::RecordSet RecordSet(ss);
    for (auto& record : RecordSet) {
        /*recEvents made and put in vector allRecEv*/
    }
    return allRecEv;
}
```

I'm tempted to just keep the `recEvent` class simple and create another `.h` file specifically for these database functions, however these functions don't require a class, so I am not sure as to how to go about this.

Comment: fetchRecEv is a public member method of recEvent, and that's why its as a member function in the cpp file

Comment: ok, I misunderstood, I'm deleting previous comment

Comment: I would prefer a different `someClass` (with a meaningful name) with a (non static) member method `fetchRecEvent`, vs a plain global function. It can help you later in modify the code if you want, e.g, use a derived `SomeInheritedClass` for fetching records, with little or no modification in client code.
In every case, I would avoid having a method `fetchRecEvent` (which could be also named `loadRecEventsFromDatabase`) in your `recEvents` class. google for Single Responsability Principle (SRP)

Comment: @GianPaolo: Why are you introducing an artificial class just so that `fetchRecEvent` can be a member? Having a `SomeInheritedClass` is not an argument. Yes, you can now change `SomeBaseClass::fetchRecEvent( )` to `SomeInheritedClass::fetchRecEvent( )` in client code. That is _worse_ than changing client code to `fetchRecEvent_withRetry( )` - both are a name change, but `SomeInheritedClass` would introduce yet another unnecessary class.

Comment: @MSalters I would go with some factory pattern: have a method `CreateRecEventLoader`, which returns a `shared_ptr<BaseRecEventLoader>`, and client code will use something such `auto loader = CreateRecEventLoader(); loader->fetchRecEvent();`. when later you will introduce a loader that read from file and not from db, just modify the factory method and return a `RecEventLoaderFromFile` (the new inherited class) and don't touch client code.(ok, methods and classes naming can be enhanced, but that's not the point).

Comment: @GianPaolo: If you want a factory, just make that return a `std::function< decltype(fetchRecEvent) >`. And when you say **method** `CreateRecEventLoader`, you're implying that is also a class member, so we're talking factory factories at this point. It looks like you're suffering from a rather severe case of Java.

Comment: @MSalter, I agree with your last comment, factory can be achieved like you say, and not only with a different class. I'm C# biased, not Java, but actually there is not much difference. The point is to write client code that can be open to implementation modification without the need to rewrite the client code. a method returning a function used in client code gets the goal. I would add to your answer the function factory suggestion

Comment: @GianPaolo and MSalters' point is that you can do that outside the keyword `class` in C++

Comment: yes @Caleth, as I told, I agree with with MSalter that you can get the goal using an `std:function` instead of a `class`. My point is that in general is better to decouple and to write code robust to further requirements changes. both my suggestion and the factory pattern returning a function get this. I don't see any problem having one more class with its method(s), no big difference from writing one or more global methods. But using a std::function is maybe the "right" way to do it in modern c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free functions are first-class citizens in C++. If there's no reason for `fetchRecEv` to be  a member of `class RecEvent`, then it's perfectly OK for it to be a free function.

Yet the function apparently  is related directly to `class RecEvent`, which is an argument in favor of sharing the same header. If you would put `fetchRecEv` in its own header, then that header would still need to include the header declaring `class RecEvent`. Nested headers are not a real improvement.

@Azeem suggests a `Utils` namespace. That's probably a bad idea. It's good C++ practice to keep free functions in the namespace to which they logically belong. This becomes essential when you need Argument-Dependent Lookup. Defining an `operator+` in a "utils" namespace simply will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've decided to move the database handling features to the main cpp file of the program, my main issue before was that functions like fetchEvents were part of class recEvents but were outputting vectors of recEvents, in short, to utilise the program, an instance of recEvents would have to be made to then use these functions? Functions that themselves create recEvents.

Comment: @DanielPeedah: Actually, a `static` method can be called without an object instance - check your C++ book for details. You would call it as `auto events = RecEvent::fetchRecEv( );` so class name instead of object name, and `::` instead of `.` in front of `fetchRecEv`.

Comment: @MSalters I think as a beginner programmer it keeps bugging me that have a method in a class that creates instances of the class, should I not be bothered?

Comment: @DanielPeedah: Well, in a sense that is perfectly normal. Constructors are methods of a class that create _one_ instance of that class. In this case, you want to create _multiple_ instances of that class with a single function call, so you can't use a constructor, but it still could be a `static` method.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to declare / define these in separate `.h` / `.cpp` files under a `Utils` namespace. Please note that the namespace `Utils` is just an idea. You should have a better idea where your free functions logically belong and to which namespace.

For example:

In `utils.h` header:

```
namespace Utils {

void doSomething();

} // Utils
```

And, in `.cpp` source file:

```
namespace Utils {

void doSomething()
{
    // ...
}

} // Utils
```

---

Apart from this, your code had some serious formatting problems. Make use of your IDE's source code formatting features so it would not take much of your time.

---

You are using [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in your code so I assume you are working with at least C++11. And, there's a raw pointer, use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) instead.

[C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) would be a quite useful resource for incorporating C++ features safely.

Comment: The question is maybe opinion based, this answer is an opinion I disagree with. See my comment on OP on why I would prefer a class method vs a global function as in your suggestion, even if enclosed in some namespace

Comment: Sorry, to make things clear, I am in an internship and am doing some code for a new part of their system while learning, I am offline and so a lot of my code does not run due to not having access to the whole platform as of yet.
I will make sure to clean up my format thank you.